# Duplicate Modules

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, python-module

In a Django app, I have an extra module. So my app is called header and inside it I have a model, view and a header file. Inside of the header file I have a class called resources which does what I want, but for some reason on a page refresh, it duplicates the information.

view:

```
def home(request):
header = Resources("home") #generate the resources for this page

return render_to_response('pages/index.html', {'header': header, 'content': test})
```

resources:

```
class Resources(object):

javascript_resources = []
javascript_files = []
style_sheets = []

def __init__(self, page_id = "home"):
    self.page_id = page_id.lower()
    self.get_status()
    self.get_meta()
    self.get_javascript()
    self.get_style_sheets()

def get_status(self):

def get_meta(self):

def get_javascript(self):

def get_style_sheets(self):
```

So what happens is, the header.javascript_resources list should only be 3 members long, but each duplicate it adds to it. So for some reason this object is staying in memory, even after a page refresh. What is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you created `javascript_resources` as class variable. Try to move its initialisation in the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 3):

`javascript_resources` is an attribute of the `Resource` *class*, so if you are adding stuff to it in subsequent requests, they will "add up".

If you want that each request has an empty `javascript_resources`, make it an attribute of the instance (i.e. initialize it in `__init__`) or empty it before instanciating `Resource`.